# I Can't create an ado.net transaction in IronPython

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, ironpython, transactions

I'm trying to create an ado.net transaction in IronPython in asp.net and I'm getting the following error
"couldn't find member Rollback"

I tried to see what's different in my ironpython ado.net transaction with a vb.net ado.net transaction but I can't see the differences or find the reason why one doesnt work and the other does. Perhaps I'm just not seeing something, these are the test codes

VB.NET

```
Partial Class prueba
    Inherits sql_conexiones

    Sub bt_aceptar_click(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim objTransaction As SqlTransaction
        Dim conpubs As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=PABLODALMA;Initial Catalog=SistemaHYM;User ID=sa;Password=usuario;Connect Timeout=180")
        Dim strUpdateA As String = "UPDATE bancos SET descripcion_banco = 'prueba' WHERE cod_banco = 1"
        Dim strUpdateB As String = "UPDATE bancos SET descripcion_banco = 'pruebados' WHERE cod_banco = 1"
        Dim cmdUpdateA As SqlCommand
        Dim cmdUpdateB As SqlCommand
        cmdUpdateA = New SqlCommand(strUpdateA, conpubs)
        cmdUpdateB = New SqlCommand(strUpdateB, conpubs)
        conpubs.Open()
        objTransaction = conpubs.BeginTransaction
        Try
            cmdUpdateA.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmdUpdateB.ExecuteNonQuery()
            objTransaction.Commit()
            Response.Write("ok")
        Catch ex As Exception
            objTransaction.Rollback()
            Response.Write("no ok")
        Finally
            conpubs.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

IronPython

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Data')             # Agrega espacio de nombres Data
from System.Data import *                   #uso esta forma para importar o la otra?
clr.AddReference('System')                  
import System                               # Agrega espacio de nombres System       

def bt_aceptar_click(sender,e):
    objTransaction = System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction
    conpubs = System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=PABLODALMA;Initial Catalog=SistemaHYM;User ID=sa;Password=usuario;Connect Timeout=180")
    strUpdateA = "UPDATE bancos SET descripcion_banco = 'prueba' WHERE cod_banco = 1"
    strUpdateB = "UPDATE bancos SET descripcion_banco = 'pruebados' WHERE cod_banco = 1"
    cmdUpdateA = System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(strUpdateA, conpubs)
    cmdUpdateB = System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(strUpdateB, conpubs)
    conpubs.Open()
    objTransaction = conpubs.BeginTransaction
    try:
        cmdUpdateA.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmdUpdateB.ExecuteNonQuery()
        objTransaction.Commit()
        Response.Write("ok")
    except:
        objTransaction.Rollback()
        Response.Write("no ok")
    else:
        conpubs.Close()
```

Something else to say it's the object inspector is showing very different objects. When VB.NET says

objTransaction System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction

- Connection        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
- IsolationLevel        ReadCommitted(4096)

IronPython says
objTransaction Microsoft.Scripting.BoundBuiltinFunction with a wider set of subitems. This probably means something related to the problem but I dont have the technical level to know it. There are some references to the object being related to an ado.net transaction, such as "public member" --> instance --> "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction". 
Is IronPython creating the object I need or it's just creating another type of object and that's why I'm getting the error?

Comment: BeginTransaction() <-- missing brackets?

Comment: if you post your commentary as an answer, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have a minor syntax error. Try adding brackets after *BeginTransaction*, as follows:

```
objTransaction = conpubs.BeginTransaction()
```